# PHP - using variables in arrays in a for statement

Tags: php, arrays, schedule

First, i'd want to excuse myself in case this question has already been posted and anwsered, but since english isn't my primary language, i guess i couldn't find or know the correct words to find it.

So i am making a schedule which grabs it's data from a schedule that is already made and i'd like a for loop inside an if statement to loop around an array which is defined by the day. My current code:

```
if($hoursandminutes >= 1435 && $hoursandminutes < 1520) {
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) {
        $p2a1 = "property$x";
        $p2a11 = $results->results->collection1[8]->$p2a1;
        echo "$p2a11 <br>";
    }
}
```

So I believe this is pretty self explanatory and it works the way it should. But the problem is that the "collection" array which is indexed, contains the data for different days of the week, for example collection1[0], collection1[1] contains the data for the subject we have first and second on monday and collection2[0], collection2[1] have the same, but for tuesday. So what i'd like to do, is to have the:

```
$p2a11 = $results->results->collection1[8]->$p2a1;
```

part but with the "collection" array being dependent on the day. 
This is what i currently have, but it doesn't work:

```
$day = date('w');
$dantest = "collection$day";

if($hoursandminutes >= 1400 && $hoursandminutes < 1800) {
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 2; $x++) {
        $p2a1 = "property$x";
        $p2a11 = $results->results->$dantest[0]->$p2a1;
        echo "$p2a11 <br>"; 
        echo $dantest;
    }
}
```

But it does nothing. If i try to echo $dantest which is also in the function for testing purposes, it echos "collection1" twice since the statement loops twice and today is monday ...
What am i supposed to write in the $dantest variable for the array to be correctly selected?

Thanks in advance.
Sincerely,
Thunderzzu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `$dantest` is a string,

```
$dantest[0]
```

returns the first character of that string, hence

```
$results->results->$dantest[0]
```

evaluates to

```
$results->results->c
```

To work around this, set intermediary variables:

```
$p2a11tmp = $results->results->$dantest;
$p2a11 = $p2a11tmp[0]->$p2a1;
```

or surround `dantest` with `{}`:

```
$p2a11 = $results->results->${dantest}[0]->$p2a1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
 $p2a11 = $results->results->$dantest[0]->$p2a1;
```

evaluates `$dantest[0]` as being an array and retrieving the first element (which is 'c', the first char of "collection", and thus not giving an error).

What you want is

```
 $p2a11 = $results->results->${$dantest}[0]->$p2a1;
```

in where `$dantest` is resolved first and then the rest of the expression wille be interpreted.

proof:

```
<?php
$dantest = "myarray";
$myarray = array("a", "b", "c");

echo $dantest[0];
?>
```

==> "m"

```
<?php
$dantest = "myarray";
$myarray = array("a", "b", "c");

echo $$dantest[0];
?>
```

==> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: m in - on line 5

```
<?php
$dantest = "myarray";
$myarray = array("a", "b", "c");

echo ${$dantest}[0];
?>
```

==> a

Comment: Correction: PHP does not actually treat strings as arrays when accessing them with `[]`. This becomes evident when one tries to replace a character of a string with zero or two or more characters like `$str[2] = 'xyz';`.

Comment: For some reason, the code still does not work. If i try to echo $dantest with your solution, it does indeed return collection2 as it did before but the for statement itself does not echo out what i'd want it to. Thank you for the help though, someone else already anwsered it correctly.